# Something like print END << END; in C++?

Tags: c++, string-literals

Is there anyway to do something like PHP's

```
print << END
yadayadayada
END;
```

in C++? (multi-line, unescaped, easy-to-cut-and-paste stream insertion)

Comment: These are called "Here documents" in /bin/sh and derived languages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This answer is now out of date for modern C++ - see [sbi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549257/21886) for the modern way.**

This is the best you can do:

```
std::cout <<
    "This is a\n"
    "multiline\n"
    "string.\n";
```

Not as convenient as a proper heredoc, but not terrible.

Comment: It should be noted that this isn't really any special multiline string syntax. The C and C++ languages will concatenate string literals in source code, so this is identical to `std::cout << "This is a\nmultiline\nstring.\n";` in every respect (except readability).

Answer (score 44):

C++11 has raw [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
// this doesn't have '\n', but '\\' and 'n'
R"(yada"yadayada\n)"
```

And if you need those parens, you can do that, too, using whatever you want for an end token:

```
// the following will be "(yada)(yada)(yada)"
R"END((yada)(yada)(yada))END"
```

it also works with embedded new lines:

```
// the following will be "\n(yada)\n(yada)\n(yada)\n"
R"END(
(yada)
(yada)
(yada)
)END"
```

Comment: But I think that still won't allow embedded newlines.

Comment: Is there a way to use variables inside `string literals`?

Comment: @Lanti: The obvious answer is no, since the term "literal" means the value is interpreted _literally_. But I suspect your question could be improved through actual stating what you want to do.

Comment: Right, so more specifically, there's en equivalent in C++ like ES6 Template Literals in Javascript? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals With this, you can construct full html templates like if you using Mustache, Handlebars, Nunjucks for client-side rendering, but only with JS standard library. It would be nice to have something similar in C++, to have variables inside a newline preserved strings, when the Networking TS from ASIO will hit C++: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/networking-ts-impl

Comment: Or maybe variables is not the perfect description, more like expressions, when in a newline preserved strings (like string literals, when you don't need to escaping every line with `\n` and even the leading spacing or tabs are preserved), it can store variables, expressions inside an uncommenting block like `${expression}` in JS Template Literals?

Comment: @me22 - did you try it? I assume by "embedded newlines" you mean that a line break in your source code translates to `\n` in the resulting string. I printed a string literal like this and got exactly that, and checked the hex just to make sure. ... @Lanti - I believe the best you can do is string concatenation through the preprocessor, e.g. `#define XYZ "DEF"` -> `R"(ABC)" XYZ` = `R"(ABC)" "DEF"` ~= `R"(ABCDEF)"`. With macros instead of immediate values, and maybe reusable headers, you at least have a little flexibility.

Comment: @Lanti If you want that, you'd basically have to replace the "template". In C you'd use sprintf & %s, in C++ you'd probably use a combination of substr & replace.

Answer (score 7):

In C++, it's not usually considered code style to put large amounts of data into source code so there isn't a fancy language way to do it.

It is usually more flexible to put the text into an external file (such as a text file), then it isn't bound into the compiled executable.

If you do want the text to be bound into the executable then (depending on your platform) you can often use some form of *resource* support, or an assembler with an 'incbin' style directive to give name to a data area with the text that you want.

Alternatively, you can use an external utility (such as `xxd -i`) to compiler a named C style array from a given input file. The generated file can then be compiled with the rest of the source code.

Comment: "In C++, it's not usually considered code style to put large amounts of data into source code so there isn't a fancy language way to do it." I don't think that's the reason why there's no fancy way to do it, but +1 for `xxd`

Comment: Mm, there are still some cases where it makes more sense. Working with shaders is a decent use case; generally speaking you wouldn't want to embed your shader source in your program source (any more than you would want to hard-code values in general) but doing this for a 'default' shader might be good practice, not to mention separating GL testing from complications with file ops.

Comment: (Edit timed out) - shader source would need quotes and newlines per line without the HEREDOC or alternative. Are the arguments against HEREDOC for C++ or more general? IMHO neither the string literal, manual line breaking, or external preprocessors are 'elegant', never mind 'fancy'.
Sorry to dig up a post 8 years in the dirt.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Hello
World
)foo";
//same as
const char* s2 = "\nHello\nWorld\n";
```

Whether or not it's best-practice, C++11 does pretty well exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
std::cout << "First line\n"
"second line\n"
"third line\n" ;
```

And that's the best you can do with C++.

Comment: so the answer is that it's impossible?

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as a HEREDOC in C++.

You can do

```
cout << 
"yadayadayada"
"yadayadayada"
<< endl;
```

That is the best you can get. But you still has to escape special chars like \,",'.

The way would it be to include the text as an ressource into the executable or load it from an external file.

Answer (score 0):

A slash at the end of a line means the next line is a continuation of the string.  This leads you to an alternate syntax that you may or may not prefer over other suggestions:

```
std::cout << "\
This is a\n\
multiline\n\
string.\
";
```

The advantages: you don't have to wrap each line in quotes; when importing text from some other source you only have to edit one end of each line, not both ends (more macro friendly); and you can see exactly how the resulting string will look, including leading spaces.

The disadvantages: you still have to explicitly include \n for newlines, and I don't like losing the ability to indent my code nice and pretty.  HEREDOC syntax also suffers from this feature, so perhaps that won't bother you.

Personally, this isn't a syntax I like.

Comment: I mentioned this somewhere else in the comments - is the newline behavior implementation-/OS-defined or something? I print `R"(as<Enter>df)"` and the result includes a `'\n'`. I seem to be the odd one out here. (C++11, GCC on Linux x64, if it matters.)

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly, I believe you want this:

```
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout << std::endl << "yadayadayada" << std::endl;
```

Comment: not at all i'm afraid, I guess I didn't explain that clearly. I want something that can cout (or insert to any stream) UN-escaped text. in PHP it's done like I said (im pretty sure, it's been a while), and it will print anything exactly, until it finds "END;" on a new line, on its own. actually, you can use whatever end "deliminer" you want to declare, but it has to end with a semicolon and on its own line.