# Tips for embedding a longer text in source code, as in languages like Perl?

Tags: c++, c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Something like print END << END; in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549184/something-like-print-end-end-in-c)

In a shell script or in a perl program the so called "HERE" documents are commonly used for longer text, e.g. Perl:

```
my $t=<<'...';

usage:

   program [options] arg1 arg2

      options:

            -opt1  description for opt1
            -opt2  description for opt2
...

print $t;
```

This style is very well readable, e.g. no need to escape quotes or to explicitly insert `\n`.

I am wondering if there is a comparable elegant approach to embed a longer text inside a C/C++ program?

```
#include <iostream>;
int main(void) {
  std::string t;
  // t = ... the same long text as in the perl example in a HERE document fashion ...
  std::cout << t;
  return 0;    
}
```

EDIT: Simplification: there is no variable interpolation needed.

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549184/something-like-print-end-end-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no elegant solution. I keep using:

```
std::string lorem =
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, "
"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna "
"aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation "
"...";
```

C/C++ sticks the strings together, unfortunately there's no way to enter a linebreak implicitly except using `\n`.

Besides, this is a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549184/something-like-print-end-end-in-c).

Comment: Would not compile. One of the operands have to be std::string, or, better, remove the plus signs.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate. I searched beforehand, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

I have always used

```
"....\n"
".....\n"
"....\n"
```

Which is actually one char* literal, and has the little advantage of not getting distorted when MSVC optimizes tabs.